# ¿Cómo obtener los días dentro de un rango de dos fechas?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Tengo la tabla **calendario** con todas las fechas del mes de diciembre del 2021 (sólo ejemplificaré algunas fechas dentro de la tabla, pero se sobreentiende que en realidad contiene todos los días de dicho mes):

| id | fecha |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-12-01 |
| 02 | 2021-12-02 |
| 03 | 2021-12-03 |
| 04 | 2021-12-04 |
| 05 | 2021-12-05 |

Tengo la tabla **usuarios**:

| id | nombre | no_empleado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Andrea | 101 |
| 02 | María | 102 |

Tengo la tabla **asistencias**

| id | fecha | no_empleado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-12-03 | 101 |
| 02 | 2021-12-04 | 101 |
| 03 | 2021-12-03 | 102 |
| 04 | 2021-12-04 | 102 |
| 05 | 2021-12-05 | 101 |
| 06 | 2021-12-06 | 102 |

Trabajé en una consulta para desplegar el número de empleado, su nombre, los días en los que asistió y los días en los que faltó:

```
SELECT u.no_empleado, 
       u.nombre, 
       a.fecha FROM usuarios u 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT no_empleado, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha) ORDER BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha)) AS fecha 
           FROM asistencias WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31' 
           GROUP BY no_empleado) a 
ON u.no_empleado = a.no_empleado
```

Con la consulta anterior, obtengo esto:

| no_empleado | nombre | asistencias | faltas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Andrea | 3,4,5 | 1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10... |
| 102 | María | 3,4,6 | 1,2,5,7,8,9,10... |

Ahora, la cuestión es que además de la tabla **asistencias**, debo considerar otra tabla llamada **vacaciones**. La estructura de dicha tabla es la siguiente:

| id | fecha_inicial | fecha_final | no_empleado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-12-07 | 2021-12-09 | 101 |
| 02 | 2021-12-07 | 2021-12-09 | 102 |

Y teniendo dicha tabla en consideración, deberían dejar de aparecer los días dentro de los rangos que se manejan como vacaciones en la columna de "faltas". El resultado debería ser el siguiente:

| no_empleado | nombre | asistencias | faltas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Andrea | 3,4,5 | 1,2,3,6,10... |
| 102 | María | 3,4,6 | 1,2,5,10... |

¿Cómo puedo adaptar mi consulta para obtener lo anterior?

La consulta en cuestión no puede ser adaptada a utilizar CTE dada a la versión de MariaDB que estoy utilizando. Estoy trabajando en phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente di con la respuesta:

```
SELECT u.no_empleado, 
       u.nombre, 
       a.fecha AS asistencias, 
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha)) AS fecha 
FROM calendario 
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31' 
AND (DAYOFWEEK(fecha) BETWEEN 2 AND 6) 
AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha),a.fecha) 
AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha),vac.vac_days)) as faltas FROM usuarios u 
JOIN (SELECT no_empleado, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM start_event)) AS fecha FROM events 
      WHERE start_event BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31' 
      GROUP BY no_empleado) a ON a.no_empleado = u.no_empleado 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT v.`no_empleado`, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(DAY(c.`fecha`)) vac_days FROM events v 
           INNER JOIN calendario c ON c.`fecha` BETWEEN v.`start_event` AND `end_event` 
           AND c.fecha BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31' 
           GROUP BY v.`no_empleado`) vac ON vac.`no_empleado` = u.no_empleado 
ORDER BY `faltas` DESC
```